# Как сделать, чтобы текст адрессайта.ру не переделывался в гиперссылку?

Tags: telegram-bot, ссылки

Бот отвечает в чат обычным текстом "Название магазина: Магазин.рф",
в чате это выглядит так:

> Название магазина: [Магазин.рф](https://%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD.%D1%80%D1%84)

Как сделать так чтобы Магазин.рф остался текстом, а не переделывался в ссылку?

Comment: Можно конечно использовать parse-mode <code>, но в этом случае меняется шрифт текста и он выбивается из общей стилистики оформления, и еще становится кликабельным для копирования, что может запутать пользователя не существующим функционалом.